# Couldn't found Gemfile in react-native

Tags: ruby, react-native, gemfile

I cloned react-native project from github. I tried to run on iOS simulator when I run `bundle install` it is saying **Couldn't found Gemfile**. I don't have Gemfile in my project directory. How I can create Gemfile?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bundle init`](https://bundler.io/v2.4/man/bundle-init.1.html) to create a `Gemfile` in the current working directory.

Or you can create a very basic `Gemfile` manually with this content:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

# gem "rails"
```